# How to get macOS High Sierra file vault encryption to continue/How to cancel encryption and decrypt drive?

Tags: encryption, filevault, high-sierra

On my MacBook Pro Mid 2015 running macOS High Sierra I was trying to encrypt it using FileVault.

I can’t tell if progress is stuck or just moving very, very, very slowly

What are ways I can get the encryption to continue, or just cancel the encryption and decrypt the drive?

Comment: Same as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268817/how-long-will-filevault-encryption-take-can-i-stop-it ?

Answer (score 5):

You can check the status from the terminal with `diskutil cs info /Volumes/<name>` and look for `Conversion State` and `LV Conversion Progress`. If you want to cancel the encryption with `diskutil cs revert /Volumes/<name>`

```
srv:~ onik$ diskutil cs info /Volumes/OSX
Core Storage Properties:
   Role:                       Logical Volume (LV)
   UUID:                       00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
   Parent LVF UUID:            00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
   Parent LVG UUID:            00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
   Device Identifier:          disk1
   LV Status:                  Online
   Conversion State:           NoConversion
   LV Conversion Progress:     100%
   Content Hint:               Apple_HFS
   LV Name:                    OSX
   Volume Name:                OSX
   LV Size:                    126804688896 B
```

Oh, and if you're using APFS (new in High Sierra), the commands are `diskutil apfs list` and `diskutil apfs decryptVolume /Volumes/<name>`

Then you can wait  15 minutes and check again. The conversion should continue and might go faster if you log out or just restart your machine and don’t log back in.

There’s no need to reinstall the operating system in almost all cases. You may need to leave the machine running for a day or two if for some reason it’s not progressing at a good rate. There also is no cancel. It needs to proceed or you could wipe the entire disk and reinstall everything.

Comment: Attempting to halt encryption of an APFS volume using…

`diskutil apfs decryptVolume /Volumes/Name`

…results in the error…

`Error starting background decryption of APFS Volume: The given APFS Volume is already encrypting or decrypting (-69573)`

If there's a way to stop encryption of of an APFS volume, an hour of online research has failed to reveal it to me.  This is particularly vexing given that High Sierra sometimes silently converts HFS+ volumes to APFS when encryption is requested.

Comment: Yeah, none of the older solutions for Sierra and earlier seem to work on High Sierra. Also, the encryption process uses very little CPU and disk I/O for some reason. I'd rather it just go ham for an hour and get it over with.